# Angular http POST to get JWT token returns 200ok with parsing error

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt, angular-httpclient

I have been trying to receive a JWT token from my web api through my angular web app. I am able to successfully retrieve the JWT token string, but I am receiving a parsing error that I cannot seem to fix.

This is the response after I send the correct credentials via POST to my web api endpoint:

> Object { headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:52706/api/auth/token", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:52706/api/auth/token", error: {…} }

As you can see, I am getting a 200ok response and the token is actually in the console when I expand the error:

> error: {…}
>   error: SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"
>   onLoadhttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:28768:46invokeTaskhttp://localhost:4200
>   text: "eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3htbGRzaWctbW9yZSNobWFjLXNoYTI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiQ29keVdpbHNvbiIsIlVzZXJSb2xlIjoiQWRtaW4iLCJPcmdJRCI6.dIOAIODWIOJDJjwiadjoiawjdjoiAOIJWDijoawdji838DHWJHio"

Here is my Angular login funtion:

```
loginUser(user) {
const creds = user.username + ":" + user.password;

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: "Basic" + btoa(creds)
  })
};

return this.http.post<any>(this._loginUrl, user, httpOptions);
}
```

Here is my login-component typescript:

```
loginUser() {
//console.log(this.loginUserData);
this._authentication
  .loginUser(this.loginUserData)
  .subscribe(res => console.log(res), err => console.log(err));
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I decoded the returned token - it looks like a deformed JWT.  The brackets are messed up.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that the Firefox console was cutting off the full response token, so I made up a fake token for this post. The real token works just fine if I were to throw it into Postman. The correct token is now in the post.

Comment: Authorization: "Basic" missing space ? it should be "Basic "

Comment: Hmm, authorization basic, or authorization bearer?

Comment: Yes you re right  for JWT is Bearer

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate - Angular's `HttpClient` attempts to parse JSON by default, but this *isn't* JSON and so it fails.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I had looked at that post and tried adding the response-type as text. I received the same error.

Comment: Double-check that you set `{ responseType: 'text' }` inside of `httpOptions` and not inside of `headers`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin That was it!

Comment: @CAlex  I'm unable to add ```{ responseType: 'text' }``` inside of httpOptions. its showing an error. how did you do

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting a JSON object back or just the JWT as a string? If you are getting the JWT as a string then JSON parse will fail because there is no JSON in the response.

Add `responseType: 'text'` to your `httpOptions` to handle a return string.

```
loginUser(user) {
const creds = user.username + ":" + user.password;

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Basic' + btoa(creds)
    }),
    responseType: 'text'
};

return this.http.post(this._loginUrl, user, httpOptions);
```

Comment: I am getting the token back as a string.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent Angular trying to parse your token as a JSON, you need to set `responseType: 'text'`.

Try this:

```
loginUser(user) {
    const creds = user.username + ":" + user.password;

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Basic" + btoa(creds)
    });

    return this.http.post<any>(this._loginUrl, user, {
        headers: headers,
        responseType: 'text'
    });
}
```